# Error while converting a class to byte array and viceversa?

Tags: java, stream, arrays

I need to send an `Object` as bytes array to another method which itself will return another bytes array from an Object.

This is the code I've got for calling method:

```
byte[] bytesArray;
Gato gatito = null;
Gato gato = new Gato();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;

try {

out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
out.writeObject(gato);
bytesArray = bos.toByteArray();
} 

finally {
out.close();
bos.close();
}

System.out.println("Gatito es nulo? "+gatito==null);
byte[] huntedCat = cliente.method(bytesArray);

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(huntedCat);
ObjectInput in = null;
try {
in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
gatito = ((Gato)in.readObject()); 
} finally {
bis.close();
in.close();
}

System.out.println(gatito.nombre);


}
```

And so this is the method called which actually performs quite same operations:

```
public byte[] method(byte[] something) {

  byte[] bytesArray = null;
  Gato gato = new Gato();
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutput out = null;

  try {

    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
    out.writeObject(gato);
    bytesArray = bos.toByteArray();
    out.close();
    bos.close();

  } 
  catch(IOException e) {

  }

  return bytesArray;
}
```

I'm always getting an error so program halts and `getMessage` from exception says `Gato` which is the class I'm converting to bytes array.

Comment: Don't swallow your exceptions, handle them.

Comment: whats the error? use try...catch...finally. you are ignoring exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that your `Gato` class doesn't implement `Serializable`?

See: [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) (JavaDocs)